# Is it possible to use coordinates from a table in one .csv file to delete columns in a second .csv file using R?

Tags: r

I am using two .csv files; the first is a matrix that contains spatial data, while the second has data related to the cells defined in the first file. I am trying to use the first file to inform the second and automate it as a script. An example of the first file is below:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
1   0  2  0  0  0
2   0  0  3  3  5
3   5  0  2  0  0
4   0  0  0  0  1
5   0  1  0  4  0
```

I am then using the following to return which coordinates contain a certain value (e.g '5'):

```
which(matrix==5, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Which returns this:

```
    row col
3    3   1
2    2   5
```

What I am hoping to do is to use this information (that is, which cells contain '5' in this instance) to select which data to analyse/plot in the second file. An example of second file is below:

```
 Seconds    row1/col1   row1/col2   row1/col3   row1/col4   row1/col5
   0        60.32       60.11       59.85       60.04       61.01
   0.25     61.22       61.01       59.99       60.54       61.23
   0.5      62.45       61.87       60.34       61.02       61.99
```

I have read of numerous ways to remove a column from the second file, but it is very large and so removing columns manually by the names returned from file 1 is impossible. Is it possible to delete or ignore columns from the second file based on the output from the first file (so that only data showing a '5' in the first file is analysed in the second)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you care about the columns / rows where the data came from (in your 2d .csv) or can you just extract all the data into a list and then manipulate that list ? Maybe you want to keep the time ? Maybe you want to have some kind of way to keep the order ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - yes, I would like to keep the time and order of the second file. Ideally I would like to create a subset of the original file that just contains the data relevant to the cells identified from the first file.

Comment: Ok, I'm not an R expert but I have two 'ideas' : Maybe you can change all the values you don't want to 'NaN' so you only keep to good data without changing the matrix. Or you can 'export' the 'good data' into a new matrix with header `Seconds Value OriginalCol` ? An entry would be `0.25 61.23 col5` or `0.5 62.45 col1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
m <- read.table(header=T, text="X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
1   0  2  0  0  0
2   0  0  3  3  5
3   5  0  2  0  0
4   0  0  0  0  1
5   0  1  0  4  0")
idx <- which(m==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
df <- read.table(header=T, check.names=F, text="  Seconds    row1/col1   row1/col2   row1/col3   row1/col4   row1/col5
0        60.32       60.11       59.85       60.04       61.01
0.25     61.22       61.01       59.99       60.54       61.23
0.5      62.45       61.87       60.34       61.02       61.99")
cols <- paste0("row", idx[,1], "/col", idx[,2])
cols <- c(names(df)[1], intersect(names(df), cols))
df[,cols,drop=F]
#   Seconds row1/col1 row1/col3 row1/col4 row1/col5
# 1    0.00     60.32     59.85     60.04     61.01
# 2    0.25     61.22     59.99     60.54     61.23
# 3    0.50     62.45     60.34     61.02     61.99
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, that's great.

Comment: Sorry, hit return too early...

Thanks for your quick response, that's great. Unfortunately, when I apply it to my full dataset I only receive one truncated column in response. Can I just check that I have interpreted your code correctly?

Am I right in saying that essentially you have replaced the former column headers with the IDs returned using 'idx', and are then returning any columns that include these IDs?

Comment: The variable `cols` contains the column names to retain from `df`. `c(names(df)[1], intersect(names(df), cols))` also includes the 1st column of `df`, and it makes sure that only existing columns are included.

Comment: Ah I see - I figured out why I was seeing a truncated return from your script (I was using 'skip' in read.csv), however for some reason when I apply it to my full dataset it is only returning the very first column. Everything appears to be working as it should until I reach
    c(names(df)[1], intersect(names(df), cols)). I will keep playing around with it, many thanks for your help.

Comment: You may wanna check `names(df)` and `cols` before you reach that line - do they match? Also note that `read.csv` may alter the column names if you do not use `check.names=F`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and Happy New Year. I have checked the above and 'names(df)' and 'cols' match in their output (that is, both return a list of results in the same format). I am using 'check.names=F' but I still only receiving the first column back. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Happy New Year. If the problem persists, you may wanna edit your original question and add the data + code as an reproducible example. This would make debugging easier.